# Error al instalar GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, instalacion, grub

Acabo de instalar la versión más actual de ubuntu y terminó diciéndome que no se había podido instalar correctamente el grub,

> La instalación del grub-install/dev/sda falló.

He probado multitud de opciones de Internet y ninguna dio resultado.
He instalado el Boot-repair y me ha sacado esta información https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tcXFfsSjk8/

sdc1 es el pen drive desde el que he instalado el Boot-Repair para intentar solucionar el problema

Comment: `You need to be logged in to view this paste.` Edita la pregunta y agrega esos logs. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.